# How To Count Number Of Items In XML Doc

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm new here - and I guess you guys are the best - so here goes.

Here's my problem.  I was dared to create an entire blog site based solely on XML - no databases.  So far, I'm doing very well.  I just have one issue that is holding me back from finishing this project all together.

I have a "Blog Comments" xml document like this:

```
<comments>
    <blogId id="123">
        <commentID>46</commentID>
        <userName>user1</userName>
        <userComment>This is a test comment</userComment>
    </blogId>
</comments>
<comments>
    <blogId id="123">
        <commentID>47</commentID>
        <userName>user2</userName>
        <userComment>this is a test comment by some user</userComment>
    </blogId>
</comments>
<comments>
    <blogId id="1244">
        <commentID>129</commentID>
        <userName>user3</userName>
        <userComment>This is someone else's comment</userComment>
    </blogId>
</comments>
```

I would like to be able to count the number of comments attached to the first blogId node(?).

So far, I have opened the doc and am able to read, but I don't know how to count....
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = //your xml document

//to get the count of comments with the first id:
var blogs = doc.Descendants("blogId");
var firstId = blogs.First().Attribute("id").Value;
int count = blogs.Count(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == firstId);

//this seems more useful to me:
var commentsByBlogId = doc.Descendants("blogId").GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("id").Value);
```

Comment: I tried to give a path location of the "XDocument" but got an issue with "Cannot Convert Type String" to System.Xml.LINQ.XDocument.

I tried this (because the app would have never known where to look for the xml document):
XDocument doc = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/BlogComments.xml");

I even tried to do this:
XDocument doc = "~/App_Data/BlogComments.xml";

Comment: That's not the proper way to load a file as an `XDocument`.  If you look at the `XDocument` documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx you can find the `Load` method that does what you're trying to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371.aspx

Comment: So... then, this opens it up and counts the number of comments related to that particular blog:
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("BlogComments.xml", LoadOptions.None);

                    //to get the count of comments with the first id:
                    var blogs = doc.Descendants("blogId");
                    var firstId = blogs.First().Attribute("id").Value;
                    int count = blogs.Count(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == firstId);

                    lmkComments.Text = count + " Comments";
                    lmkComments.NavigateUrl = "blogComments.aspx?BlogId=" + BlogId;

Comment: Ok, I tested it and it works great!  Thank you for your help!  I really do appreciate it.  As soon as I get the styling done, and it is up and running, I will post a link so you can see what you helped build. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = XDocument
     .Load("c://blog.xml")
     .XPathSelectElements("//comments/blogId[@id='123']")
     .Count();
```

Comment: That's cool.. but I'd like to count THIS: "<blogId id="123">" within This: "<comments>".  Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you have this figured out but I think my edits would work.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this - another scenario. very similar:    <Reatctions>
        <blogId id="1234">
            <userName>foo</userName>
            <reaction>1</reaction>
        </blogId>
    </Reatctions>
I want to count the field "reaction" under 1 blog id.. who would that work?

Comment: "//reactions/blogId[@id='1234']/reaction"

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  Best of both worlds :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ you can do a simple query `doc.Descendants("Comment").Count(x => x.Attributes["id"] == "123")`.

I am writing this without Visual Studio, the attribute may be addressed a little differently and if you want to use this code more often you should consider adding basic error handling (i.e. the "id" attribute does not exist).